# Train an existing opencv model with new data

Tags: c++, opencv, decision-tree

I'm using the opencv Decision Trees for create a classifier. I would like to know if it is possible to retrain that model (that can be saved and loaded in a .yml file) adding new data. The version of Opencv that i'm using is 2.4.

I was thinking on something like this

```
CvDTree dtree;
dtree.load("existingTree.yml");
dtree.train(newValues, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, newResponses);
```

newValues contains only the new samples and newResponses contains the classes for that values. This would generate a new decision tree trained with the old values of the first training process and this new ones?

I didn't find any information on opencv documentation about this.

Comment: from intuition it should be possible to create samples from an existing dt which (used in a new training) should create the same tree fast. But really just intuition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: During training, when a decision tree is passed a large training set, each split node in the tree learns a feature set and a corresponding threshold. The branches of the tree terminate with leaf nodes that then stores the prediction values. If you have already trained a decision tree, then it has already learned, from a training set, all the features, threshold and prediction values. Training it again with a additional data would render the previously learned parameters useless.

Another way to look at this would be to think of Random Forest, which is formed by an ensemble of trees. Given that your new dataset is not too different from the data that the model has previously seen. If you want you can train a new tree and add it to a group of previously trained trees. During prediction, you can average the prediction of all trees to get an overall prediction.